# How to find the greatest value among players uploaded data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a hi-score type of tool for my app, so I am playing around with some code and cannot figure out to search through multiple nodes to find the greatest value. The problem seems to be that the DataSnapshot reads the nodes as a HashMap and isn't having problem converting the values to an int. 
How can I read through the information (player name and player score), have the DataSnapshot identify the greatest value and set the TV to that value?

The code for what I have tried is below. I will also add a screenshot of how my firebase looks to make it visually easier to understand

My WriteToFirebase Activity

```
public void gFirebase(View view){

        int score = (int) (Math.random() * ((50)+1));
        Player p1 = new Player();
        p1.setName("Player 1");
        p1.setScore(score);

        DatabaseReference roofRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference gameInfoRef = roofRef.child("hiscore").child("player_name").push();

        gameInfoRef.setValue(p1);

    }

    public void lFirebase(View view){

        int score = (int) (Math.random() * ((50)+1));
        Player p2 = new Player();
        p2.setName("Player 2");
        p2.setScore(score);

        DatabaseReference roofRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference gameInfoRef = roofRef.child("hiscore").child("player_name").push();

        gameInfoRef.setValue(p2);

    }

    public void sFirebase(View view){

        int score = (int) (Math.random() * ((50)+1));
        Player p3 = new Player();
        p3.setName("Player 3");
        p3.setScore(score);

        DatabaseReference roofRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference gameInfoRef = roofRef.child("hiscore").child("player_name").push();

        gameInfoRef.setValue(p3);


    }
```

My ReadFromFirebase Activity

```
public void readFromFirebase(View view) {

        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference hiscoreRef = rootRef.child("hiscore").child("player_name");
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                int hiscore = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    int value = ds.getValue(Integer.class);
                    if (hiscore < value) {

                        hiscore = value;

                    }
                    Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(hiscore));
                    ChangeMe.setText(hiscore);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        };
        hiscoreRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
}
```

The expected result is for the textview on my screen to change to the highest number in my Firebase system (The highest score)

JSON tree of my database

```
{
  "hiscore" : {
    "player_name" : {
      "-Lo0W8ks7WCEsrym5Qpl" : {
        "name" : "Player 3",
        "score" : 24
      },
      "-Lo0W92WqeUMdq_y7J8M" : {
        "name" : "Player 2",
        "score" : 42
      },
      "-Lo0W9KjzXE_XCU4K8MN" : {
        "name" : "Player 1",
        "score" : 43
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a snippet of the JSON from the relevant part of your database (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: I have done this now. @AlexMamo

Comment: So basically you want to get the highest score from those three objects which is 43, right?

Comment: Yes, correct. To read through the values and identify the highest score which would be 43.

Comment: You forgot to use @AlexMamo so I can see your comment. In the meanwhie Frank van Puffelen provided a perfect answered ;)

Comment: Haha, Sorry @AlexMamo I'm still getting used to Stack. Thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Firebase query for this. That will make the server perform the check, instead of having to do this in your own code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference hiscoreRef = rootRef.child("hiscore").child("player_name");
Query hiscoreQuery = hiscoreRef.orderByChild("score").limitToLast(1);
hiscoreQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int hiscore = 0;
        for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            hiscore = ds.child("score").getValue(Integer.class);
        }
        Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(hiscore));
        ChangeMe.setText(hiscore);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }

});
```

You may receive a warning about needing to define an index, in which case you can add this to your Firebase security rules:

```
"hiscore": {
  "player_name": {
    ".indexOn": "score"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for your answer. This code also seems to provide me with the error "Failed to convert a value of type java.util.HashMap to int". Is this because of the Firebase security rules? The code just crashes the app. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Woops... good point, it's reading the wrong field. I updated the code to fix that.

Comment: Thanks Frank. This fixed my issue! I've added this as the solution. If I wished to find the name of the player with the highest score, would this query but much different?

Comment: To also get the name, also do this in the loop: `ds.child("name").getValue(String.class)`

Comment: Hey Frank. I was reading the documentation and understand your answer a lot better, but I'm unable to figure out how to loop through the dataSnaphshot and pull anymore data than the first value from limittolast or limittofirst. To do this do you use a Listener? If the data exists?

Comment: You wanted a single highscore, so that's why the code here only has a single `int` variable. If you want multiple values, you'll need an array or `List` and add the items to in inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Would that mean using a 'for' loop instead of the for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) ?

Comment: No, it's in that exact same loop.